# Angular file drag and drop not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, file-upload

I have created a file upload component in Angular that uses the `@HostListener('drop', ['$event'])`. In Firefox I receive the files I drop in `event.dataTransfer.files`, but for some reason Chrome will always return the same event object with an empty list instead of the `File` objects for the files I dropped.

Here's a snippet of the file drop listener

```js
@HostListener('drop', ['$event'])
  public onDrop(evt: any) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    document.getElementById('dropzone')?.classList.remove('hovering');
    console.log(evt); // Returns an event object without any files in it.

    for (let i = 0; i < evt.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
      // ... do stuff
    }

    // Add files to input field programmatically
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('form-file-input') as any;
    if (fileInput && fileInput.files) {
      fileInput.files = dataTransfer.files;
    }

    // Fire change event
    fileInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  }
```

And my relevant HTML

```html
<div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
  <label for="form-file-input">Drop files here</label>
</div>

<input
  type="file"
  id="form-file-input"
  name="file"
  class="form-control file-upload"
  [formControl]="formControl"
  [formlyAttributes]="field"
  accept="image/*"
  style="display: none"
/>
```

I am also using Formly to create the forms but I'm pretty sure the bug isn't in there since all relevant code gets executed. I just don't receive the file object from the client.

Comment: Maybe, when a file is dropped, for Angular it is not droped in the input.

Comment: I manually add the file to the input, but that's (kinda) off topic here. In FF I get the file object (at that console.log) which I can then add to the input, but in Chrome the `evt` object doesn't contain any files.

Comment: I found Chrome 107 breaks drag drop files, fine with other version or Firefox

Answer (score 0):

You should handle all of the drag drop events via HostListener.

Here is the code:

```
 @HostListener('dragover', ['$event']) public onDragOver(evt: DragEvent) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
  }
  @HostListener('drop', ['$event']) public onDrop(evt: DragEvent) 
  {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    console.log('drop');
  }
  @HostListener('dragleave', ['$event']) public onDragLeave(evt: DragEvent) 
  {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    console.log('dragleave');

  }
```